# A specific format for nice tables

Tags: tables, fonts, color, newtx

With this code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, isotope}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
\textbf{Osservabile} & \textbf{Simbolo} & \textbf{Operatore associato} \\
\toprule
Posizione & $\bar{r}$ & $\bar{r}$ \\
Momento & $\bar{p}$ & $-i\hslash \overline \nabla$ \\
Energia potenziale & $  \mathcal{U}$ &  $\mathcal{U}(r)$ \\
Energia cinetica & $\mathcal{K}$ &  $-\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m}\nabla^2$ \\
Hamiltoniana & $H$ & $-\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m}\nabla^2+\mathcal{U}(r)$\\
Energia totale & $E$ & $-i\hslash\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Numeri di massa} & \textbf{Elemento chimico} & \textbf{Prodotto iniziale} & \textbf{Prodotto finale}\\
\midrule
$4n$ &  Torio   &   \isotope[232][90]{Th} &   \isotope[208][82]{Pb} \\
$4n+1$ &  Neptunio   &  \isotope[237][93]{Np}  &  \isotope[209][83]{Bi}  \\
$4n+2$ &  Uranio   &  \isotope[238][92]{U}  & \isotope[206][82]{Pb}  \\
$4n+3$ &  Attinio   &  \isotope[235][92]{U}  &  \isotope[207][82]{Pb} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I'm finding to create two tables that they have the same structure of the below picture:

[image]

**1.** I would like to create as the upper image, the label (same color) of the table in upper case with a different character (I use into my book [`URW Classic`](https://ctan.org/pkg/classico) as Sans Serif character (`\fontfamily`) and by default as normal text character is `newtxtext`, the clone of `Times`).

See this example for the figure below:

[image]

**2.** A thicker line with the same color as the image if possible;

**3.** The comment of the table must be with the character `newtxtext`;

**4.** A slightly larger space between rows in my second table. Precisely between one chemical element and the other below.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see, if the following solution is close to what you after:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % <---
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}                % <---
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            makecell}                         % <---
\setcellgapes{3pt}                            % <---
\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                    % <---
\arrayrulecolor{teal}                         % <--- 

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}                % <---
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}}   % <---
    \captionsetup[table]{font=bf,             % <---
                         labelfont={teal,bf},
                         singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]              % <---
    \makegapedcells                 % <---
    \caption{My fancy table}        % <---
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{>{$}c<{$}}}   % <---
    \toprule[2pt]                   % toprule thickens you can change according 
                                    % to your taste, for example to 3pt or more
\textbf{Osservabile} & \textbf{Simbolo} & \textbf{Operatore associato}  \\
    \midrule
Posizione           & \bar{r}       & \bar{r}                           \\
Momento             & \bar{p}       & -i\hslash \overline \nabla        \\
Energia potenziale  & \mathcal{U}   & \mathcal{U}(r)                    \\
Energia cinetica    & \mathcal{K}   & -\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m}\nabla^2    \\
Hamiltoniana        & H             & -\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m}\nabla^2+\mathcal{U}(r) \\
Energia totale      & E             & -i\hslash\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{My another fancy table}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule[2pt]      % <---
\thead{Numeri\\ di massa}     
        & \thead{Elemento\\ chimico}     
                        & \thead{Prodotto\\ iniziale}   
                                                    & \thead{Prodotto\\ finale}\\   % <---
    \midrule
$4n$    &  Torio        &   \isotope[232][90]{Th}   &   \isotope[208][82]{Pb}   \\
$4n+1$  &  Neptunio     &   \isotope[237][93]{Np}   &   \isotope[209][83]{Bi}   \\
$4n+2$  &  Uranio       &   \isotope[238][92]{U}    &   \isotope[206][82]{Pb}   \\
$4n+3$  &  Attinio      &   \isotope[235][92]{U}    &   \isotope[207][82]{Pb}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

so far i consider only tables in your mwe (it not contain your table 13.1, if you will provide code for this table content, i will show solution example for it too)

**edit:**
differences between above and your mwe are indicated by `% <---`. as you can see, above are added packages `xcolor` for coloring table rules as well font for tables' labels, `makecell` for adding more vertical spaces around cells contents and for macro `\thead`, which enable to write column heads in two (or more, if necessary) lines, `caption` for defining caption style (font family and color, positioning of caption).

in above mwe tables are not horizontally centered. if you like to have them centered, just add `\centering` after `\begin{table}[...]`. but in this case the caption will be aligned with left text border. for aligning it width beginning of table, you should use `threeparttable` as shown in mwe below. in it is also added a way how to select font used in caption and have upper case font in caption label (indicaed by `% <===`). so far i select `iwona`, but you can replace it with font of your wish. also the thikness of rules are defined globally.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,italian]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, 
            threeparttable}       % <---
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
    \captionsetup[table]{font={large,teal,bf},
                         labelformat=uc,                                 % <===
                         singlelinecheck=off}                               

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering                  % <---
   \begin{threeparttable}       % <---
    \caption{My fancy table}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{>{$}c<{$}}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Osservabile} & \textbf{Simbolo} & \textbf{Operatore associato}  \\
    \midrule
Posizione           & \bar{r}       & \bar{r}                           \\
Momento             & \bar{p}       & -i\hslash \overline \nabla        \\
Energia potenziale  & \mathcal{U}   & \mathcal{U}(r)                    \\
Energia cinetica    & \mathcal{K}   & -\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m}\nabla^2    \\
Hamiltoniana        & H             & -\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m}\nabla^2+\mathcal{U}(r) \\
Energia totale      & E             & -i\hslash\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}        % <---
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering                  % <---
   \begin{threeparttable}       % <---
    \caption{My another fancy table}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
\thead{Numeri\\ di massa}
        & \thead{Elemento\\ chimico}
                        & \thead{Prodotto\\ iniziale}
                                                    & \thead{Prodotto\\ finale}\\
    \midrule
$4n$    &  Torio        &   \isotope[232][90]{Th}   &   \isotope[208][82]{Pb}   \\
$4n+1$  &  Neptunio     &   \isotope[237][93]{Np}   &   \isotope[209][83]{Bi}   \\
$4n+2$  &  Uranio       &   \isotope[238][92]{U}    &   \isotope[206][82]{Pb}   \\
$4n+3$  &  Attinio      &   \isotope[235][92]{U}    &   \isotope[207][82]{Pb}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}        % <---
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page borders)

Comment: @Sebastiano, any news?

Comment: Kind friend Zarko, I've connected now after a hell of a day since yesterday. :-(. I am not very good with tables and my knowledge is modest. I was reflecting on whether your code, copied into my very long code, does not conflict with the compilation.

Comment: @Sebastiano, i was just curious if i understood your question correctly and if i addressed all your issues in it. i hope, that today you are better.

Comment: My question is: You have put `\fontfamily{iwona}`. Is it possibile for to write with horizontal strech character **TABELLA 1 or 2** with the font `URW Classic` instead of iwona? (see the last image of my question - number red 3). I must declare `\fontfamily{urw}`? Same font for the caption: My fance table?

Comment: All in all, it's fine/okay and I hope you can give me the information that I've given you. Maybe tomorrow it will be better.  I am under continuous stress every day (correction of all types of tasks, meetings, etc..). When I connect here I relax a lot but obviously it's not enough.

Comment: you can use your font. i just use font which is installed in my system. if you will have problems with this, ask new question (you now, one problem per question :-) )

Answer (score 5):

- `\arrayrulecolor` from the `colortbl` package for the rule color
- `captionsetep` and `captionof` commands from the `caption` package for the caption settings
- `toprule[3pt]` for a top rule 3pt thick
- `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`  for increasing row size by a factor of 1.5
- To get the table centered and the caption starting at the table left limit:  Put the table content inside a `minipage` environment of width equal to the table width then put the minipage inside a `center` environment

!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, isotope,colortbl,caption}

\arrayrulecolor{cyan}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=cyan,sc},justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,skip=2pt}

\newlength{\mytablewidth}
\newsavebox{\mytablebox}

 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\savebox{\mytablebox}
{\begin{tabular}{lcc} 
\toprule[3pt]
\textbf{Osservabile} & \textbf{Simbolo} & \textbf{Operatore associato} \\
\toprule
Posizione & $\bar{r}$ & $\bar{r}$ \\
Momento & $\bar{p}$ & $-i\hslash \overline \nabla$ \\
Energia potenziale & $  \mathcal{U}$ &  $\mathcal{U}(r)$ \\
Energia cinetica & $\mathcal{K}$ &  $-\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m}\nabla^2$ \\
Hamiltoniana & $H$ & $-\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m}\nabla^2+\mathcal{U}(r)$\\
Energia totale & $E$ & $-i\hslash\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\settowidth{\mytablewidth}{\usebox{\mytablebox}}
\begin{minipage}{\mytablewidth}
\captionof{table}{my first table}
\usebox{\mytablebox}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{center}
\savebox{\mytablebox}{\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule[3pt]
\textbf{Numeri di massa} & \textbf{Elemento chimico} & \textbf{Prodotto iniziale} & \textbf{Prodotto finale}\\
\midrule
$4n$ &  Torio   &   \isotope[232][90]{Th} &   \isotope[208][82]{Pb} \\
$4n+1$ &  Neptunio   &  \isotope[237][93]{Np}  &  \isotope[209][83]{Bi}  \\
$4n+2$ &  Uranio   &  \isotope[238][92]{U}  & \isotope[206][82]{Pb}  \\
$4n+3$ &  Attinio   &  \isotope[235][92]{U}  &  \isotope[207][82]{Pb} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\settowidth{\mytablewidth}{\usebox{\mytablebox}}
\begin{minipage}{\mytablewidth}
\captionof{table}{my second table}
\usebox{\mytablebox}
\end{minipage}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your work and I have appreciated it.

Comment: You are welcome! @Sebastiano

Comment: You're always welcome to me.