# Combination of TikZ and special tables: difficulty

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, fonts, color, newtx

With reference to two previous questions [A specific format for nice tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475000/a-specific-format-for-nice-tables) and [Some adjustments of a nice table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475115/some-adjustments-of-a-nice-table)  of mine to which I had an excellent answer from all users, I for example used a combination of the code of @Zarko and @marmot.
I obviously chose a part of my very long code to be used to create a compilable MWE. If I compile this extract I already have errors:

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor. [\definecolor]
>
> Undefined control sequence. [\arrayrulecolor]
>
> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\arrayrulecolor{t]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,italian]{article}
\usepackage{babel,newtxtext}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,isotope,tikz}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,table,x11names]{xcolor} 
\definecolor{mgreen}{RGB}{150,196,95}
\definecolor{nteal}{RGB}{60,172,147}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\definecolor{nteal}{RGB}{60,172,147}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% @Zarko code %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable}       % <---
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2} 
\DeclareCaptionFont{cond}{\color{nteal}\fontfamily{CabinCondensed-TLF}\selectfont}
\DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{black}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\captionsetup[table]{font={small},
                     labelformat=uc,
                     labelfont={cond,bf},
                     textfont=teal,
                     singlelinecheck=off}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% @marmot code %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\DeclareCaptionFormat{Sebastiano}{%#1#2\par
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex]{%
\node[fill=mgreen,text=white,font=\bfseries\sffamily\large,rounded
corners=0.2em,minimum width=1.8em,minimum height=1.8em](M){#1};
\draw[very thick,mgreen] (M.west) -- ++ (-1,0);}}%
\hfill\hfill{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(R);
\draw[very thick,mgreen] (M.east) -- (M.east-|R);
}}\par
#3} 
\DeclareCaptionFormat{Incredibile}{%#1#2\par
{\tikz{%
\node[text width=\linewidth-4pt,outer xsep=1.6pt,align=justify](MI){\textbf{\sffamily#1#2}#3};
\draw[very thick,mgreen] (MI.north west) -- (MI.south west)
(MI.north east) -- (MI.south east);
}}\par
} 
\captionsetup{format=Incredibile}
\captionsetup[sub]{format=Sebastiano}
\newcommand{\IncludeClippedGraphics}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[rounded corners=5pt,clip,preaction={draw=mgreen,very thick},inner sep=-2pt]{%
\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Le quattro serie radioattive con $n\in \mathbb{N}$.}
\makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\thead{Numeri\\ di massa}
        & \thead{Elemento\\ chimico}
                        & \thead{Prodotto\\ iniziale}
                                                    & \thead{Prodotto\\ finale}\\
    \midrule
$4n$    &  Torio        &   \isotope[232][90]{Th}   &   \isotope[208][82]{Pb}   \\
$4n+1$  &  Neptunio     &   \isotope[237][93]{Np}   &   \isotope[209][83]{Bi}   \\
$4n+2$  &  Uranio       &   \isotope[238][92]{U}    &   \isotope[206][82]{Pb}   \\
$4n+3$  &  Attinio      &   \isotope[235][92]{U}    &   \isotope[207][82]{Pb}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

At this moment I do not understand how to fix the errors and if I have forgotten to insert some package or macro indispensable. It is no coincidence that the rows are not colored.

[image]

The thing I don't understand is that in my structure.tex file where there are all the packages and macros, during the compilation of my book, I observed that
not loaded the font `CabinCondensed-TLF`,

[image]
using this extract

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2} 
\DeclareCaptionFont{cond}{\color{nteal}\fontfamily{CabinCondensed-TLF}\selectfont}
\DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{black}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\captionsetup[table]{font={small},
                     labelformat=uc,
                     labelfont={cond,bf},
                     textfont=teal,
                     singlelinecheck=off}
```

A month ago everything worked perfectly but now I don't understand the motivation and how to solve the problem.

Comment: `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor. [\definecolor]` that is not the format of a latex error message. show the error from the log file (the help text for that messgae tells you what the clashing options are). `Undefined control sequence. [\arrayrulecolor]` that is also not the format of a tex error message but if you mean that `arrayrulecolor` is undefined you need `colortbl` package.

Comment: Is  `cabin` your default sans font, or do you want to set it so?

Comment: @Bernard Kind Bernard for the text I use `newtxtext`, for the caption of the images I use `urw-classico` (clone of `Optima` font). For example: Fig. 1 (Optima) text (newtxtext). For tables there was `CabinCondensed-TLF` + `newxtext`. I currently I have not understand because this font no works as before (see my answer for @David where I have added the screenshots). For me another different font but nice is fine, the important thing is that it is different.

Comment: I asked the question, because I can make the label with Cabin Condensed (which is a nice font I sometimes use, b.t.w.), but I have to load the `cabin` package, which makes Cabin  the default sans font.

Comment: I've posted a simple solution for the label font and the option clash, which doesn't require loading `cabin`. Is it what you want?

Comment: @Bernard Perfect! Thank you very much for you and David. Grazieeeeeeeeeee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution for the label font and the options clash:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt ,italian]{article}
    \usepackage{babel,newtxtext}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, dvipsnames, table, x11names}{xcolor}
    \usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, isotope, tikz}

    \definecolor{mgreen}{RGB}{150,196,95}
    \definecolor{nteal}{RGB}{60,172,147}
    \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{caption}
    \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
    \definecolor{nteal}{RGB}{60,172,147}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% @Zarko code %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable} % <---
    \setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt} % <---
    \setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt} % <---
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
    \arrayrulecolor{teal}
    \usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}
    %\DeclareCaptionFont{cond}{\color{nteal}\fontfamily{CabinCondensed-TLF}\selectfont}
    \DeclareCaptionFont{cond}{\color{nteal}\usefont{T1}{Cabin-TLF}{condensed}{sc}}
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{black}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
    \captionsetup[table]{font={small},
                         labelformat=uc,
                         labelfont={cond,bf},
                         textfont=teal,
                         singlelinecheck=off}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% @marmot code %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


    \DeclareCaptionFormat{Sebastiano}{%#1#2\par
    {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex]{%
    \node[fill=mgreen,text=white,font=\bfseries\sffamily\large,rounded
    corners=0.2em,minimum width=1.8em,minimum height=1.8em](M){#1};
    \draw[very thick,mgreen] (M.west) -- ++ (-1,0);}}%
    \hfill\hfill{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(R);
    \draw[very thick,mgreen] (M.east) -- (M.east-|R);
    }}\par
    #3}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{Incredibile}{%#1#2\par
    {\tikz{%
    \node[text width=\linewidth-4pt,outer xsep=1.6pt,align=justify](MI){\textbf{\sffamily#1#2}#3};
    \draw[very thick,mgreen] (MI.north west) -- (MI.south west)
    (MI.north east) -- (MI.south east);
    }}\par
    }
    \captionsetup{format=Incredibile}
    \captionsetup[sub]{format=Sebastiano}
    \newcommand{\IncludeClippedGraphics}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rounded corners=5pt,clip,preaction={draw=mgreen,very thick},inner sep=-2pt]{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htb]
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    %\caption{\fontfamily{CabinCondensed-TLF}\selectfont Le quattro serie radioattive con $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$.}
    \caption{Le quattro serie radioattive con $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$.}
    \makegapedcells
    %\caption{\fontfamily{CabinCondensed-TLF}\selectfont Le quattro serie radioattive con $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    \thead{Numeri\\ di massa}
            & \thead{Elemento\\ chimico}
                            & \thead{Prodotto\\ iniziale}
                                                        & \thead{Prodotto\\ finale}\\
        \midrule
    $4n$ & Torio & \isotope[232][90]{Th} & \isotope[208][82]{Pb} \\
    $4n+1$ & Neptunio & \isotope[237][93]{Np} & \isotope[209][83]{Bi} \\
    $4n+2$ & Uranio & \isotope[238][92]{U} & \isotope[206][82]{Pb} \\
    $4n+3$ & Attinio & \isotope[235][92]{U} & \isotope[207][82]{Pb} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first error message is

```
l.5 \definecolor
                {mgreen}{RGB}{150,196,95}
? h
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [svgnames,dvipsnames,table,x11names]
Adding the global options:
  ,svgnames,dvipsnames,table,x11names
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
?
```

actually the issue is that xcolor is loaded by tikz so you can't load it later with different options, load it earlier:

```
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,table,x11names]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,isotope,tikz}
```

The document then runs without error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. But do you get the character CabinCondensed-TLF back in the table? +1 for the previous answer.

Comment: Using Papeeria TeX-Live 2019(new) I have the same problem of the unloaded character CabinCondensed-TLF: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape T1/CabinCondensed-TLF/bx/n' undefined(Font) using T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 59.`

Comment: I get `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/CabinCondensed-TLF/bx/n' undefined` which isn't surprising as I have neither the font nor a latex fd file for it. You presumably had the font if you had it working